# Yesod - AppMessage as argument to message

Tags: haskell, yesod

In Yesod, what if I would like to put an AppMessage as an argument to a message, as in this example:

```
ElemError field@AppMessage description@Text: #{field} deve conter apenas #{description}. Cuidado com espaços.
```

Comment: Can you add more detail to this question? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. A good reference is the Yesod book [chapter on Internationalization](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization), though.

Comment: The parameter type would be of a message.